# Can't see the script code in google sheets script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets with a script code in the script editor,
I know there is a code there but it shown like this:
[image: my script editor]

How can I see my code?

Thank you!

Comment: scroll up or press CTRL+A

Comment: Try getting to the project via the Gsuite Developers Hub.

Comment: scroll up or press CTRL+A not working. what is it 'Gsuite Developers Hub'?

Comment: How many lines does the code have? What is the the name of the file? Code.gs You might have accidentally created a new, empty file. If so - if you scroll up, at the left you should have a list of different files?

Comment: My code is about 20 lines, Code.gs this is the name of the file. I created an empty file, than I can see new code. but if I pasted a code, this is happen again...

Comment: So can you see and open code.gs? Because the gs file opened in your screenshot has a different name.

Comment: This is the code.js file, its written in Hebrew

Comment: I tried to close the specific file (code.js) and opened it again, And I see the code, but can't add nothing and when I scroll up it is disappear again...

Comment: This is  strange. If you can, before the code disappears, press Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C to select and copy the code. Then, just try to create a new project and paste your code inside.

Comment: The code is not disappear, just hidden. when I pasted a code from another file, I can see it, but when I scroll t is disappear again :(

Comment: Does it happen only in one file? If so, maybe the easiest would be to create a new file and remove the one that causes you trouble.

Comment: I did it yet :(

Comment: Do you have some extension or something that is mucking with the CSS of the online editor? Looking at that screenshot it looks like the line number gutter is way wider than it should be.

Comment: right, but I dont have any css file its a new file,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.
For me, it was because of the RTL of the site you can fix this by changing your first language to English in your Google account (you can keep Hebrew or any other RTL language as second or later).